# How to change the default output from a Maven 2 / Cobertura instrument goal?

Tags: java, testing, maven-2, code-coverage, cobertura

when i instrument my classes using Maven 2 using the command

> mvn cobertura:instrument

The output (the instrumented classes) are put in \target\generated-classes. Is there a way to change the output location to \target\classes?

I checked the instrumentation tasks of the cobertura-maven plugin but this does not give me a solution sofar.

Comment: Pascal. Did you find a solition for this that would enable the instrumented classes to be generated in the classes folder, and further, be picked up by m2eclipse to be published to tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the instrumented classes are only needed by cobertura for report generation. If you create them in `target/classes`, they will overwrite the original class files.

If you need the instrumented files in a jar as a result, you can configure the `maven-jar-plugin` to pick up the files from the `target/generated-classes` directory instead of or in addition to the files from the standard `${build.project.outputDirectory}`.

**Edit**

Have a look at the [maven-jar-plugin description](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/index.html). To only use `target/generated-classes`, the following addition to your POM should work - try it and modify it to your needs:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version> <!-- replace with correct version nbr! -->
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>${project.build.directory}/generated-classes/**/*.class</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>${project.build.directory}/classes/**/*.class</include>
          </excludes>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

`${project.build.directory}` points to your target folder, `${project.build.ouputDirectory}` to target/classes. I do not know if you can simply set `${project.build.ouputDirectory}` to a new value - have a look at the [this chapter of the maven book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html), maybe you find some hints

**Edit 2**

Alternativly or additionally you can use maven to copy the files from target/generated-classes to target/classes after `coberture:instrument` has finished. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512516/how-to-copy-from-one-file-to-another-in-maven) has one answer with an example POM (fragment), you just have to identify the correct phase (process-resources is definitely too early for your case)

Comment: That would be optimal to overwrite the target/classes, in that way the packaging of my wars, jars and ears will be untouched. Is it enough to overwrite/set the ${project.build.outputDirectory} for generation or packaging?

Comment: I need those instrumented classes inside my jars/wars and ears. So i am looking for a way on how to accomplish this the easy way.

Answer (score 3):

You have not said why you want to overwrite the default location, but I assume it is so that you can use the instrumented classes from another project, or perhaps include them in a web archive or something similar.

I added the following to my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>instrumented-classes</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>instrumented</classifier>
                <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-classes/cobertura</classesDirectory>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This makes maven generate an additional jar file called projectname-instrumented.jar

It is then possible to depend on this jar file from any other pom (including for example a web module) using

```
<depends>
    <group>mygroup</group>
    <project>projectname</project>
    <version>1</version>
    <classifier>instrumented</classifier>
</depends>
```

I did not test this 100% but have used similar mechanisms in the past

Answer (score 1):

Did you try "mvn cobertura:instrument install"? It will generate a jar file including all the cobertura version classes.
If you want to change back original version, just run the command without "cobertura:instrument".

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented the solution proposed by Andreas_D, modified my pom and uses the maven-resources-plugin. So on some stage of my build the Cobertura generated files are copied to the /target/classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it using `<classesDirectory>[Your DIR]</classesDirectory>`

Answer (score 0):

In cobertura-maven-plugin version 2.4 this is still not supported. I've just created an [improvement ticket](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-138), patch is attached to the ticket.