# Maven copy resources

Tags: java, maven

In the resources in the profile folder there is a configuration file, depending on the profile it should be taken and put in the resource root

Actually, what I encountered

1. He puts it in the project itself, and not in the original jar
2. When the second time you collect this file already comes
3. So that the folder itself in the jar does not fall

   ```
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>copy-properties</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                       <resources>
                           <resource>
                               <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/profile/${profile.dir}</directory>
                               <includes>
                                   <include>server.properties</include>
                               </includes>
                           </resource>
                       </resources>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>

       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${maven-ejb-plugin.version}</version>
           <configuration>
               <filterDeploymentDescriptor>true</filterDeploymentDescriptor>
               <archive>
                   <manifest>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                   </manifest>
                   <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
               </archive>
               <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   ```

Tell me where I was wrong?
In which plugin to configure maven-ejb-plugin or maven-resources-plugin

I have **src/main/recoursces/profile/**

- serverA/server.properties
- serverB/server.properties
- serverC/server.properties

I want jar 
- It did not have a folder profile
- and have one server.properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a resource or another in Maven depending on the target environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512516/how-to-copy-a-resource-or-another-in-maven-depending-on-the-target-environment)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. I believe the resources phase `package` is not correct, it should be on a previous one like `process-resources`.

Here you have the [Maven Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)

**process-resources**: copy and process the resources into the destination directory, ready for packaging.
**package**:    take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.

Comment: I change but file don't copy to jar =(

Comment: I add some info

Comment: i am using `install` without any problem.